# RangeError nodejs socket.io

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

I am getting the following error

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at TCP.hasOwnProperty (native)
    at _hasBinary (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/has-binary/index.js:49:45)
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
// var responseHandlerRouter = require('./routes/responseHandlerRouter.js');

routes = require('./routes');

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});

io = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io').listen(server);

app.use('/', routes(io));
```

**route.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


module.exports = function (io) {

    // all of this router's configurations



    router.post('/paymentResponse', function (req, res, next) {
    io.sockets.emit('notification', res);
    res.end('well finally I am here');
});


    return router;

}
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.js"></script>

        <script>

        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

        socket.on('notification', function (data) {
           console.log(data);
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id='messages'></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I post to the URL http://localhost:3000/paymentResponse, I am getting this error in the terminal running the nodejs server.

Answer (score 0):

You're serializing the entire response object (your `res` argument), which might be causing the stack overflow due to circular references. Don't serialize the entire response object but cherry pick the properties you need.

Comment: So I wont be able pass the entire response as json ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The response object is not for sending through. It encapsulates the server response and is for setting up the HTTP response while inside a request handler.